# Help finding a replacement part?

Tags: replacement

I have a subwoofer that my friend and I found so I do not know too much about it. When I was transporting it, it fell and one of the knobs on the front was broken. I took it apart to see if I could fix it but I also found the PCB was cracked so I was wondering based on the photos I attached if anyone could help me find replacements for the part? If you need more images to figure it out I can take more.

Also, I did not know where to get help and found this website by accident so if you know of a place that would be better suited for my question that would also be helpful. Any response would be helpful and I just want to say thank you in advance.

Image Links:

Front: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T9I_n-4sjTiFXymQBnEnkVgmnY3sH_1N/view?usp=sharing

Back: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1giOTlkqJHowH1bMDENl7vEU6BqpArBqp/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

It will be a struggle to find a replacement board, but you can probably fix it if you have any soldering skills, or know someone who has.  Once the copper tracks are mended I’d suggest using epoxy resin as a mechanical repair and then you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the response but what about just the knob at the top of the board (right under the name) it's completely broken could I replace that and if so do you know what it would be called to get a new one?

Comment: @Steve: the control probably uses a standard-sized shaft, in which case you can choose from quite a variety of knobs. For example: https://www.jameco.com/shop/StoreCatalogDrillDownView?langId=-1&storeId=10001&catalogId=10001&freeText=knobs&search_type=jamecoall

Comment: Ah I see - VR4 is damaged, not just the knob itself.  This is a potentiometer but it’s not in a package/form factor that I’ve seen before, so I can’t really help there

Comment: thanks anyways just finding out its called a potentiometer was useful and something I didn't know before